# What does "to be kinetic" mean in context (applied to a person)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

This is about using the adjective *kinetic* (related to, exhibiting, motion, *kinesis*/[AHDotEL](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=kinetic&submit.x=0&submit.y=0); dynamic/energetic, a kinetic performer/[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinetic)) to describe someone in a composition with a contrasting element:

> He was kinetic and yet totally in control.
>
> [*Life in Motion: An Unlikely Ballerina*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OLLsAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT223&ots=Zcj1FZhAxO&dq=%22He%20was%20kinetic%20and%20yet%20totally%20in%20control.%22&pg=PT223#v=onepage&q=%22He%20was%20kinetic%20and%20yet%20totally%20in%20control.%22&f=false), Copeland, Jones

Seemingly not so common when used as an adjective with *he/she* and the verb *to be* ([*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_PRON%20was%20kinetic%2C*%20was%20kinetic%2C*_PRON%20is%20kinetic%2C*%20is%20kinetic%2Che%20was%20kinetic%2Cshe%20was%20kinetic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit_PRON%20was%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20was%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Benergy%20was%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20was%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*_PRON%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit_PRON%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhat_PRON%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt_PRON%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Benergy%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhich%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhalf%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhat%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmotion%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsystem%20is%20kinetic%3B%2Cc0)). *Kinetic* is most definitely of Greek [origin](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=kinetic&allowed_in_frame=0). Yet it feels (to me) it's more often used with inanimate objects, with science (*kinetic energy* etc.). Upon reading the quote it reminded me of someone being *ecstatic*, something going *ballistic*, or a *magnetic/kinetic* type of personality and such, because it rhymes I guess and I'm not clear as to what this means beyond the idea of motion. But someone per se being *kinetic*, is that emotion or motion? Is that moving or dancing?

---

- Is that a typical, idiomatic and expressive use of *kinetic* in
  context?
- What is the meaning of *kinetic* here, what does the expression mean, and what are the connotations the composition carries?

  - Is that a classical ballet term? Is there an ellipsis of some noun i.e. what is really kinetic here? I'm not clear on the context (the impression from the person walking up the stage or the performance or a state of being of the performer per se)
  - Had one said he was *ballistic but on target*, or
    *bouncing off the walls yet always in control*, or just that he had *amazing movement coordination*, how would that be different?

Comment: It's also unclear to me, and I'm a native speaker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics, there are two types of energy **potential** and **kinetic**.

**Potential energy** is just that, something that **has the possibility of happening**.  An apple hanging from a tree, a book on a table.

Once the apple or book falls from their perch, the potential energy is transformed into **kinetic energy**, it is realised as **movement** with possibly secondary vibrations or ripples which can be felt.

In your excerpt

> He was kinetic and yet totally in control.

The author is using her vocabulary of movement to describe the appearance of ***Prince*** on stage, the energy he exuded, his movements, and his dancing.  She is saying he was moving quickly and energetically, but was still in control.   If you've ever seen Prince perform, you will know that he is always in control.

Also with performers, they can be described as being **kinetic** at an energetic level. **Electric** might be a good synonym where the performer takes on a buzzing/humming quality with their presence, like a high voltage transformer.

**Ballistic** would imply a singular, sudden unidirectional movement.
**Bouncing off the walls** would imply movement without intent.

Neither would be appropriate for describing how Prince moves and  performs.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful. So would you say it's some metaphor then or is that a metonymic use? Why doesn't _ngram_ yield much... is that a newer/modern extension of the meaning? Are you implying some specific register when you say the _author is using her vocabulary_? _He was moving energetically_ : Is there any value in distinguishing between the performance and the man insofar as the term applies here? I do know the artist. I would say an electrifying yet controlled performance but I'm no native speaker and I'm curious, plus this poses a challenge for translating to FR. Thanks!

Comment: The author is using her vocabulary as she is a dancer and dancers view movement differently than mere mortals, just as musicians hear music differently.  They will see movement, when we may not, so my feeling is she saw something.  Prince, the man, moves very slowly and deliberately from what I've been told by a friend who used to wait on him at a restaurant he frequented, he's also a picky eater. As you will know, Prince, the performer, is very stylised and can be electric.  The description was about Prince's presence on stage. (cont'd)

Comment: There is an amusing story by [Kevin Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Smith) about Prince [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LhcParuzpc)

Comment: "[...] so my feeling is she saw something". I agree. I thought maybe this sort of use was frequent but not on ngram, but seeing the language you used both in the A. and here, which is more compatible with what I expect, I can see now that it's meaningful within a context, which includes something personal, some insight, rather than a very very typical idiom imho. Also did watch K. Smith, and that was a blast, thanks. Considering how unique the artist is, maybe a unique way of describing his demeanor or presence on stage etc. is fitting. Thank you!